# How to column-level encrypt in Dynamics CRM 2015?

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm-2015

I know that Dynamics CRM 2015 comes with encryption on for specific fields.

```
EmailServerProfile  IncomingPassword
EmailServerProfile  OutgoingPassword
Mailbox             Password
Queue               EmailPassword
UserSettings        EmailPassword
```

I want to use the built-in encryption feature to encrypt custom fields (columns). My instance of CRM has SSL and Data Encryption enabled.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Query to find encrypted columns.

```
SELECT [TableColumnName], [IsEncrypted]
  FROM [Our_Organization].[MetadataSchema].[Attribute]
  WHERE IsEncrypted = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen anything saying that you can encrypt custom fields, so I Think the answer is "no".

Comment: That's weird. In the `MetadataSchema` table, there is  a field `IsEncrypted`. There is also this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481562.aspx However no details on encryptions.

Comment: Yes, but no custom fields are available yet to my knowledge.